# Can valuemap widget be set to allow new entries

Tags: qfield

I am testing qfield for use in tree surveying. I wish to have a dropdown list of tree species. But I also need to be able to capture values not in the list. Can the valuemap widget be configured to allow entries not in the predefined list?